# CMake fails looking up mingw headers

Tags: cmake, mingw, sdl, sdl-2

Trying to change FindSDL.make to work with SDL2. The problem is that using mingw it doesn't find `SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR`, even though SDL2 is installed.

I've change the whole file, but the problems is in this line:

```
find_path(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES
    SDL.h
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    include/SDL2
)
```

Thought it should look up MinGW folder, but it looks like it doesn't.

Actually, even this one doesn't work:

```
find_path(TEST_PATH stdio.h)
```

So what is the proper way to use find_path under mingw on Windows? Can it be related to mingw install path (preferred one is `C:\MinGW`, but I've installed it to `E:\Programs\MinGW`)?

Should I always explicitly write `-DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=<my path to mingw>\include` or use environment variable that points to mingw folder and use it as a `HINT` to `find_path`?